# Can the server choice in Frozen Synapse be changed at any time?

Tags: frozen-synapse

I just created an account and I'm being asked to pick a server to connect to. Is this choice as binding as it would be in (say) League of Legends (airtight containers where you can't see anything of what's outside and you can't switch at a later time), or as free as it is on (say) Quake 3 (where you can join and leave servers at your heart's desire and it doesn't really matter)?

[image]

Also, why is there no online count for the 'ORIGINAL' server? Is it, in any way, special or something?

Comment: Note: The [Frozen Synapse Humble Bundle](http://www.humblebundle.com/) was released today.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that ORIGINAL used to be called the "Grand Server," but I'm not actually sure what's up with it.

Comment: It's really lame that you have to restart the game to switch servers!

Comment: Apparently Frozen Synapse is going to merge _ALL_ the servers in UK1 anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get asked this question every time you sign in. Your account is not bound to a server.

In practice, everyone ever is always on the UK server, really.

Comment: A word about the 'ORIGINAL' server? (I added that bit in a second moment.)

Comment: @badp I honestly have no idea.